# Laravel 5.1 issues with generating PDF & {!! Form::text or {!! Form::textarea

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf

I started to learn Laravel (nice framework), and being more and more familiar with it. But I arrive at a point where I don't understand why and how..

I generate a PDF from one of my view. The view is just composed by 3 `{!! Form::text` , which are filled by Varchar (length:2000) coming from my database.

I well generate the PDF but i can't understand why the text inside goes totally out of the the `{!! Form::text` in the `.pdf`-file.

I can't understand why the text stand inside the `{!! Form::text` for the first lines, but at the last one, the text will go out of the box and keep being writing until it touch the right margin of the pdf, and so diseapper..

I try to play around with `{!! Form::text` or `{!! Form::textarea`: same results..

I try to play around with `" 'rows' => '15', 'cols' => '100',"` parameters: same results...

Does someone might have an idea on why the text doesn't want to stay inside its `{!! Form::textarea` for description/sentiment and position forms?

My view:

```
@extends('template')

@section('contenu')

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2> PTS | <em><strong> Weekly Comments</strong></h2>
        <h3><strong>week: {{$week_number}}</strong></h3>
        <br>
    </div>

    @foreach($comments as $comment)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3{!! Form::textarea('desk_name', $comment->desk_name, array( 'class'=>'form-control','type' => 'text', 'rows'
                    => '5', 'cols' => '5')) !!}</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3> P&L Weekly | </h3>
                {!! Form::textarea('pnl_wtd', $comment->pnl_wtd, array( 'class'=>'form-control','type' => 'text', 'rows' => '5',
                'cols' => '5')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3> P&L MTD | </h3>
                {!! Form::textarea('pnl_mtd', $comment->pnl_mtd, array('class'=>'form-control','type' => 'text', 'rows' => '5',
                'cols' => '5')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3> P&L YTD | </h3>
                {!! Form::textarea('pnl_ytd', $comment->pnl_ytd, array( 'class'=>'form-control','type' => 'text', 'rows' => '5',
                'cols' => '5')) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3>Past Week Summary</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {!! Form::textarea('description', $comment->description, ['class' => 'textarea']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3>Sentiment</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {!! Form::textarea('sentiment', $comment->sentiment, ['class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text', 'rows' =>
                        '100000', 'cols' => '100000']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3>Positions</h3>
                </div>

                <br>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="posi">
            {!! Form::textarea('position', $comment->position, ['class' => 'form-control', 'style'=>'resize: none']) !!}
        </div>

    @endforeach
@stop
```

The function from my controller:

```
public function pdfWeekly( $week_number ) {

    $picuser = Auth::user();

    $comments = Comment::where( 'week_number', '=', $week_number )->get();
    $flag     = 'pdf';

    $pdf  = PDF::loadView( 'tr.wc.emailPdf', compact( 
        'picuser',
        'flag',
        'week_number',
        'comments' 
        ) );
    $name = "Principale Trading- Week #" . $week_number . ".pdf";

    return $pdf->download( $name );
}
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Laravel is not an `language`. It is a PHP framework.

Comment: Thanks, edited :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `I can't understand why the text stand inside the {!! Form::text for the first lines, but at the last one, the text will go out of the box and keep being writing until it touch the right margin of the pdf, and so diseapper..`. Can you make an example and add a screenshot of the error? ... I previously worked with the FPDF-library and it didn't have a 'sense' of width. So it just broke the boundaries if the paragraf was too long. The solution was to either use a different element from FPDF or to refactor the text it took as input. :-/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I am going to put a screen of it. It look like this in the meantime, I have my box and my text going litteraly outside. Let me try your tip.
|--------------------------------------------|
| asasdasdasdasd asasdasdasda |
| asasdasdasdasd asasdasdasda |
| asasdasdasdasd asasdasdasdao|da asdasdasds dasdadasdaa 
|--------------------------------------------|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf use native html layouts. So your framework classes and expressions wont work here. 
Try making a divv with width 710px and put you data in that div, it won't flow out.

Comment: Hi, I haven't thought laravel framework classes and expressions is not the best to use in this case. I as started learning Laravel, I want to only use it.
Let me try your option and come back here for feedbacks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, So I didn't used Laravel Form::textarea..... but classic <div> and <P> tag, worrks perfectly ! Thanks a lot Harsh Wardhan Gaur !



<div class="row">
 <div class="panel panel-warning">
   <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center">
    <h3>Past Week Summary</h3>
    </div>
   <div class="panel-body">      
    <P>{{ $comment->description }}</P>      
           </div>
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this it is replace input or textarea to a tag like a textarea-to-text before save. I do:

```
var $html = $('html').clone();
$($html).find('textarea').replaceWith(function () {
    $element = $("<textarea-to-text>").text($(this).val());`
    $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attribute) {
        $element.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });
    return $element;
});`
```